# Very lightweight crossplatform webview that supports javascript

Tags: web-browser, cross-platform

I need a cross-platform command line tool that can open a website (http://127.0.0.1:8000/) in a window.

Obviously Chrome and other browsers can do this. However, I need the window to be **only** the content of the website. In other words, there is no such thing as an address bar, or a back/forward button, or a bookmarks feature, etc. It's just a window showing the contents of http://127.0.0.1:8000/.

As a Java programmer, I can achieve this using JavaFX. I can make a window and put a WebView in it and done. The problem with this approach is that JavaFX' WebView has bad performance in regards to intensive use of the HTML5 canvas (which I need).

In an ideal world, I would like to use Chrome without any of its interface. So the command line call would be like

```
super-lightweight-browser http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

The website at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ contains an HTML5 canvas and is drawing lots of stuff with javascript.

I am also aware of https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef. However, I feel it is overkill for my simple purposes. Also, the builds I make with it are huge (like 400MB+).

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are looking for is to be found as [chrome.app.frameless](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window) app window.

- No Frame, title, etc.
- Full HTML5 Support.
- Free
- Cross-platform
- Source on [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/)

Demo Window.
[image: App Demo]